# pyspark using mysql database on remote machine

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using python 2.7 with ubuntu and running spark via a python script using a sparkcontext

My db is a remote mysql, with a username and password.

I try to query it using this code

```
sc = createSparkContext()
sql = SQLContext(sc)
df = sql.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:mysql://ip:port?user=user&password=password', dbtable='(select * from tablename limit 100) as tablename').load()
print df.head()
```

And get this error

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.load.
>   : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

I found that I need the JDBC driver for mysql.

I downloaded the platform free one from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=472394)

I tried including it using this code in starting the spark context

```
conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/var/nfs/general/mysql-connector-java-5.1.43")
```

and tried to install it using

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
```

on the master machine, on the db machine and on the machine running the python script with no luck.

edit2

#

i tried using

```
conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/var/nfs/general/mysql-connector-java-5.1.43")
```

seems by the output of

```
print sc.getConf().getAll()
```

which is

> [(u'spark.driver.memory', u'3G'), (u'spark.executor.extraClassPath',
>   u'file:///var/nfs/general/mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar'),
>   (u'spark.app.name', u'spark-basic'), (u'spark.app.id',
>   u'app-20170830'), (u'spark.rdd.compress', u'True'),
>   (u'spark.master', u'spark://127.0.0.1:7077'), (u'spark.driver.port',
>   u''), (u'spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', u'100'),
>   (u'spark.executor.memory', u'2G'), (u'spark.executor.id', u'driver'),
>   (u'spark.submit.deployMode', u'client'), (u'spark.driver.host',
>   u''), (u'spark.driver.cores', u'3')]

that it includes the correct path, but still i get the same "no driver" error...

What am i missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the classpath for both driver and worker nodes. Add the following to spark configuration

```
conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/var/nfs/general/mysql-connector-java-5.1.43")
conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/var/nfs/general/mysql-connector-java-5.1.43")
```

Or you can pass it using

```
import os
os.environ['SPARK_CLASSPATH'] = "/path/to/driver/mysql.jar"
```

For spark >=2.0.0 you can add the comma separated list of jars  to spark-defaults.conf file located in spark_home/conf directory like this

```
spark.jars     path_2_jar1,path_2_jar2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Word Count")\
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/tuhin/mysql.jar")\
    .getOrCreate()

dataframe_mysql = spark.read\
    .format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://ip:port/db_name")\
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")\
    .option("dbtable", "employees").option("user", "root")\
    .option("password", "12345678").load()

print(dataframe_mysql.columns)
```

"/home/tuhin/mysql.jar"  is the location of mysql jar file